# In LyX with classicthesis.sty, cross-references to Chapters don't work

Tags: classicthesis

I am using classicthesis with some minor (I think) edits.
I have child documents for each chapter. Everything renders fine apart from cross references to chapters which pdflatex renders as ??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you get "??" in place of references even after compiling twice?

Comment: I think LyX automatically runs compilation twice.  All other references work, cross-referencing to sections/sub-sections is fine.  Citations are also fine.  I am using \synctex=1 in my preamble.  Looks like there is something about chapter headings that the cross-references don't like.  Also, if I place the label before the Chapter title, I get the error: Argument of \NoCaseChange has an extra }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add the same problem but I find a way to make it working.

Let's say I have :

```
Chapter 3
Test of chapter
```

If I put the label here :

```
Chapter 3
Test of chapterLABEL
```

it doesn't work.

But, putting it here :

```
Chapter 3
LABELTest of chapter
```

seems ok.

Hope it will help.

Nico

Comment: Thanks Nico, solution works well, leaves me wondering why the label has to be placed so carefully...